# Why are rake tasks stored in lib/tasks/?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

My understanding of the `lib/` directory in rails is that it stores [non-domain specific code as a best practice](https://codeclimate.com/blog/what-code-goes-in-the-lib-directory).

However, my Rake scripts are very specific to my domain.  They do things like create new models.

So is there a better place than `lib/tasks/` to store domain-specific rake scripts, or am I missing something here?

Comment: is there a reason beside `domain` specific that you want to have you're rake task, I've use it heavily in the past sharing code from domain and have no issue although it depends on the complexity, maybe you are trying to achieve something quite more complex that I do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like this idea, and I agree - lib at one point was very much a junk drawer, and as a Rails community we've moved some of the junk away, but yes Rake tasks are usually very specific application logic.

In your `Rakefile` all you have to do is `load` your new Rakefiles (exercise for the reader: iterate the files in the folder instead of specifying it explicitly.

Example:

```
require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)

Rails.application.load_tasks

load('app/tasks/my_task.rake') # <--- my custom task!!!
```

Answer (score 0):

The above is correct, but you should add the following to prevent the zeitwerk from creating the Tasks constant. (ignore if not using zeitwerk loader)

```
Rails.autoloaders.main.ignore('app/tasks');
```

You may check this in the console by calling Tasks, it should not be defined.

Another option might be to add rake tasks inside /tasks instead of app/tasks